# CSS Animation not working smoothly Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, fadein

I'm having problems with an `animation: fadein` property running smoothly on some text in Firefox.

Rather than fading in gradually like it goes in Chrome, it just seems to pop up and makes the whole thing look clunky. This also seems weird as the image has the same `fadein` instructions and fades in smoothly.

I've tried using the `-moz` prefix but this doesn't seem to help. 
Here's my code below.
Any suggestions?

```css
.fixed-center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img-fade {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  moz-text-decoration-color: white;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  ;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.75s;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  ;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.75s;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-center">
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="img-fade">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/125x149" width="125" height="149" />
    </a>
  </p>
  <h3><p><a href="#">enter</a></p></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really hard to test and quantify.  I've tried to create a side-by-side with my chrome and FF and it's identical: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6AkhvOW_8SY3dUU0pMdkY3YjA/view?usp=sharing.  What version of FF and what OS? (jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/wf6rhtbz/1/)

Comment: @JosephMarikle Weird that it's working for you. Mine doesn't do that at all. Using the latest version of FF on Windows 7.
The fade in on FF is not smooth at all, it just pops up at the last militsecond.

Comment: Do you have a specific version number?  Can you test with the fiddle link?  It could be just rendering lag.  I have another series of tests for v50, v51, and v52 on Win 7.  The only one that seems to lag is the v52, but only the first time: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6AkhvOW_8ScGhsZ1hpWTZ4V0k/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks for the videos, but whatever is happening to mine seems to be a different problem to yours. I don't have a screen recorder otherwise I would upload what I'm seeing on my screen. I'm only self taught at web design and doing this for personal use. When I come across problems with code I often get stuck on not enough background knowledge.
I essentially want one element to fade in after the other. The code seems right for Chrome, but obviously needs to work the same across all Programmes.

Comment: No, I completely agree.  Your code looks fine to me apart from the `visibility: visible` part.  I think there's probably something else going on.  It could be as simple as an image loading in causing network lag (probably solvable with preloading) or other animations causing the frame rate to drop (maybe a `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` fix).  Obviously there's a problem and we can keep guessing, but it helps to be able to reproduce the problem at will.  Doe th fiddle also demonstrate the problem for you? Can you create a minimal example that does?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Solved it! I simplified the CSS by taking out all the `animation` from the <h3> and instead used a bit of simple jQuery to make the text fade in seperately:
`$("h3").delay(550).animate({"opacity": "0.9"}, 1800);`

Answer (score 0):

just remove styling for H3 (or you can add center if you want) and do it like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/8z6sj6tr/1/

```
<div class="fixed-center">
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="img-fade">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/125x149" width="125" height="149" />
    </a>
  </p>
  <h3><p class="img-fade"><a href="#">enter</a></p></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: If I take the <h3> off the text loses all it's styling. I want to keep the text styling, while also keeping the staggered fade in. Rather than the image and the text fading in together. I guess my question could actually be, how to delay the text fading in after the image.

Comment: Like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: @CaldwellYSR It's not that the animation-delay doesn't work. Just that it doesn't fade in smoothly in FF like it does in Chrome, it just jumps in at the last millisecond.